# Couldn't get quotation marks out from string, Python

Tags: python

Hello this is the code that I try to remove the quotation marks, but it seems doesn't work

```
text = "the “anatomical sex:”Local school boards shall develop and implement policies that "
print text

remove_quotation_marks = text.replace('"', '')
print remove_quotation_marks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
text = "the “anatomical sex:”Local school boards shall develop and implement policies that "
print text

remove_quotation_marks = text.replace(text.replace('“', ''), '”', '')
print remove_quotation_marks
```

Works in my python prompt. Probably you also need an encoding set.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some smart quotes in your text. Smart quotes are a different character than straight quotes.

http://smartquotesforsmartpeople.com/

http://hashtag-labs.com/eliminating-smart-quotes

Comment: thank you!  I thought it is just normal quotation marks